# How do I write a function's code to a string?

Tags: r

Suppose I have:

```
test <- function(x) x + 1
test
function(x)
  x + 1
```

I would like to somehow save the output produced by invoking `test` to a string (i.e. the function declaration) but can't think of a way to do it.

Comment: Do you need `"x + 1"`

Comment: I would like the full string: "function(x) x + 1"

Comment: Is this after you declare the `test`. Something like `deparse(test)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `deparse`

```
paste(deparse(test), collapse = " ")
#[1] "function (x)  x + 1"
```

---

Also, if we need to extract the components of the function, use `body`

```
body(test)
```

Or split it to a `list`

```
as.list(test)
```

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for `capture.output`.

```
> z=paste(capture.output(test), collapse = " ")
> z
[1] "function(x) x + 1"
```

Comment: This works but was hoping this was going to be the last-resort solution. Is there anything better other than capture.output? No other function to just dump the definition of a function?

Comment: Coming from other programming languages (.NET, Java, etc.), creators of libraries would always love to change their toString() method so it prints their object more succinctly or prettier, etc. Having your production app and its reputation depend on how an object is printed on the command-line by a third-party developer you have no access to is generally not an accepted practice in most languages I am familiar. R is new to me so maybe the rule breaks on this one.

Comment: @Denis, in R, sometimes complex objects (or more specifically, their classes) will have `print.yourclass` methods, but I've never seen that for a standalone function.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility?

```
dput(test,textConnection("test_txt",open="w"))
```

or the same with `dump()`